# How Can I Bulk Unchecked Categories Check Box for Selected Products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, category-products, checkbox

Mistakenly i imported products with irrelevant categories, how can i Bulk unchecked categories check box for selected products by csv or anything.

Comment: You want to uncheck or you want to assign correct category to the products?

Comment: @PurushotamSharma : uncheck

Answer (score 1):

use `getCategoryIds` and `setCategoryIds` property of product model

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cat=$product->getCategoryIds();
//remove category id from $cat array
$product->setCategoryIds($cat); //set it again
$product->save();
```

Comment: I agree your point, but i need particular products category unchecked

Comment: 100k products in my site, just 10k products categories mistakenly imported with various categories, so how can i unchecked, is it possible using CSV

Comment: make array of that products and load collection then just remove that  categories from product @Aveeva

Comment: Bro i don't want unchecked all categories, just unchecked selected products, is it possible using CSV

Comment: how many such categories are there ? @Aveeva

Comment: In my site 330 categories,

Comment: I am using CSV to assign categories for my products. is possible to unchecked from using csv

Answer (score 1):

I am giving short example you can use it your own way.

```
//first we will remove all products from category 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(<Your_Category_ID>);
$category->setPostedProducts(array()); // this will remove all products from category. 
$category->save();

// now we will assign right product to category with below code 

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(<Your_Category_ID>);
$category->setPostedProducts(<here array of product id which you want to assign>); // this will remove all products from category. 
$category->save();
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks

Comment: I agree your point, but i need particular products category unchecked

Comment: Yes prepare one list with right category and right product id then you can use above code so it will remove first all product from category and then assign it to correct category

Comment: 100k products in my site, just 10k products categories mistakenly imported with various categories, so how can i unchecked, is it possible using CSV

Comment: Bro i don't want unchecked  all categories, just unchecked selected products, is it possible using CSV

Comment: I am using CSV to assign categories for my products. is possible to unchecked from using csv

Comment: Yes but with above code if you will  make some change then you can manage easily I have done this many time.

Comment: In my site 330 categories,

Comment: No problem for that you can create list of right category with right product id 
Then it would be better you run your script with command line because this will take time and in command line it will not face time out issue.

Comment: How can i use more than one category :: $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(11,12); ---> this one not wokring.

Comment: you can use  $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')-getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id",array("in"=>(1,2,3)); and then $category->load();

In this collection you will get all categories which you have passed in addAttributeToFilter.

Comment: Pls correct me : https://justpaste.it/1f6ft

Comment: Actually what you want to achieve please clear that so I can correct my answer.

Comment: Bulk unassigned products from categories.